# Why the answer is "that" in "The area that the city now occupies..."?

Tags: grammar, transitivity, optional-that

Here is my test:

> The area ....... the city now occupies was originally swampland.
>
> A. that
> B. where
> C. on which
> D. on that

I chose B, but the answer is A. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

> The area that the city now occupies was originally swampland.

"Occupy" is a [transitive verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/transitiveverb.htm), which means it needs a direct object (a recipient of an action), so it has to tell ***what* does it occupy.**

To answer that, you can say:

- The area that

...but not:

- The area where
- The area on which
- The area on that

Comment: Expanding on this answer: a city does not occupy *in* or *on* an area.